# How to get the exact path to the script that was loaded in Lua?

Tags: lua

What I am trying to do is perform "hot-reloading" of lua files as I work on them.

My problem is that I don't know how to match the file that changed with entries in the `package.loaded` table.  While I can guess it, I was wondering if the full path is stored anywhere.

Given a file called `mymodule.lua`, when we run this:

```
local x = require('mymodule')
```

First lua looks in `package.loaded` to see if it's already loaded.  If not, then Lua looks for modules using the `LUA_PATH`, which we can see at runtime like so:

```
> print(package.path)
/usr/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua
```

After the above module is loaded, we can see that it's loaded by looking for it in the `package.loaded` table like so:

```
> for i,v in pairs(package.loaded) do
>> print(i, v)
>> end
debug   table: 0x55fa3bfe8b80
table   table: 0x55fa3bfe51e0
math    table: 0x55fa3bfe7820
mymodule    table: 0x55fa3bfe60f0
_G  table: 0x55fa3bfe2bc0
utf8    table: 0x55fa3bfe8700
bit32   table: 0x55fa3bfe9070
os  table: 0x55fa3bfe68f0
package table: 0x55fa3bfe4860
io  table: 0x55fa3bfe54e0
coroutine   table: 0x55fa3bfe4f90
string  table: 0x55fa3bfe7560
```

My approach for handling hot-reloading is to null out the entry in this table `package.loaded.mymodule = nil` and then reload the script again like so
`require('mymodule')`  This appears to work fine - the module is reloaded.

But then there are caveats...  For example, if the module is actually setup as `myproject/mymodule/init.lua`, and this is loaded like so `require('mymodule')` then the entry in the package.loaded table will simply be `mymodule` and not something more helpful in this case such as `mymodule/init.lua`  I have no way of knowing that it's the `init.lua` file that I need to watch instead of `mymodule.lua`

In m case, I track the files in C.  My challenge is that I have to somehow guess which entry in the `package.loaded` table goes with which file.

What I'd like to know is if there's a table somewhere that contains the path to whatever .lua files are loaded so that I can just monitor that list.

Maybe `package.loaded` is the wrong place to look?

Comment: Lua does not save the module's file path.  But the file path is passed to the module as second argument on Lua 5.2+.

Comment: Also, note that not all modules load from files. It is possible preload any module or even staticaly link with host app and just register open function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to modify two searchers to collect module file paths into table `package.loadedfrom`

```
-- this block should be at the beginning of the main script
do
   assert(_VERSION:match"^Lua 5%.[2-4]$")  -- only for Lua 5.2+
   package.loadedfrom = {}

   local function save(modname, loader, path)
      if type(loader) == "function" then
         package.loadedfrom[modname] = path
      end
      return loader, path
   end

   local orig_searcher_2 = package.searchers[2]
   package.searchers[2] =
      function(modname)
         return save(modname, orig_searcher_2(modname))
      end

   local orig_searcher_3 = package.searchers[3]
   package.searchers[3] =
      function(modname)
         return save(modname, orig_searcher_3(modname))
      end
end

-- now require all your modules
require"mymodule"
require"mymodule2"

-- now get the list of module file paths
for modname, filepath in pairs(package.loadedfrom) do
   print(modname, filepath)
end
```

Comment: This worked.  In my code, I refactored this a bunch so that it works with any number of searchers (I register one in my own code) Thanks!